# Hide graphics using ArcGIS JS API 4.7

Tags: graphic, arcgis-js-api

With ArcGIS JS API 4.7, is there a way to show/hide graphics per attribute?
There is a property for the graphics called visible, but when I do set it to false `myGraphic.visible = false` no change occurs.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share an example that reproduces your issue. I just did a test, and I do not see any problem with graphic visibility in v4.7.
Here is an example plunkr:

Live example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fM5kORwv4U0U3qo2dWJ6?p=preview)

```
`function changeGraphicVisibility() {
      polygonGraphic.visible = !polygonGraphic.visible;
      var spanElement = document.getElementById("visibility");
      spanElement.innerHTML = polygonGraphic.visible;
    }....`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am doing is storing all the graphics in an list, `graphicsList`, and then for example I do `graphicsList[0].visible = false`, in order to hide it. However, even though I can change the colour or other properties, this command doesn't cause any change for me.. I will try your way of using the previous value of the `visiblle` property.

Comment: I don't think it will change something to take the previous value of the visible attribute. I think it must be a object reference issue. Try to reproduce your issue in a plunker or something similar and I will try to help ^^